# Qual é a maneira mais eficiente de redimensionar bitmaps no Android?

Tags: android, desempenho, memória, bitmap

Quando um dispositivo possui resoluções de tela menores, é preciso redimensionar os bitmaps para otimizar sua exibição no display de forma adequada.

O problema é que o uso de [createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)) pode gerar um monte de erros de falta de memória depois de redimensionar um conjunto de imagens pequenas.

Qual é a maneira mais eficiente de redimensionar bitmaps no Android?

Comment: Você conhece o [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)? Para quem mexe com imagem, é uma biblioteca essencial. Talvez ele até otimize tudo isso para você, não sei.

Answer (score 4):

> Esta resposta é resumida a partir do artigo [Loading large bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html),
>   que explica como usar `inSampleSize` para carregar um `bitmap` de baixa escala
>
> Em particular, [Pre-scaling bitmaps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HY9aaXHx8yA&index=28&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE) explica os detalhes de vários métodos,
>   mostrando inclusive como combiná-los, e quais são mais eficientes para a memória do dispositivo.

Existem três caminhos dominantes para redimensionar um bitmap no Android, aonde cada um possui propriedades diferentes de memória:

**[createScaledBitmap API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean))**

Esta API levará em um bitmap existente , e criar um bitmap NOVO com as dimensões exatas que você selecionou.

No lado positivo, é possível obter exatamente o tamanho da imagem que você está procurando. A desvantagem  é que esta API requer um `bitmap` *existente* para funcionar. Isto é, a imagem teria de ser carregadada, descodificada e um mapa de bits ser criado, antes de ser capaz de criar uma nova versão , menor .

Este procedimento é ideal para obtenção de suas dimensões exatas , mas horrível em termos de sobrecarga de memória adicional. A maioria dos desenvolvedores de aplicativos que tendem a se preocupar com a memória evitam usar este método.

**[inSampleSize flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize)**

`BitmapFactory.Options` possui uma propriedade referenciada como `inSampleSize` que irá redimensionar sua imagem e decodificá-la ao mesmo tempo, para evitar o processo de decodificação para um `bitmap` temporário.

O valor *inteiro* usado aqui irá carregar a imagem reduzindo à metade de seu tamanho. Basicamente, o resultado será sempre um fator de 2 vezes menor do que sua imagem fonte.

Quando falamos sobre memória, `inSampleSize` é uma operação extremamente rápida. Efetivamente, ela irá decodificar cada pixel da sua imagem. Entretanto, existem dois grandes problemas ao usar `inSampleSize`:

- **Você não terá resoluções exatas**. Esta função somente reduz o tamanho do seu bitmap pelo fator de 2.
- **Esta função não produz a melhor qualidade de redimensionamento**. Muitos filtros de redimensionamento produzem imagens de ótima aparência através da leitura de blocos de pixels, e em seguida os ponderando para produzir o pixel em questão. `inSampleSize` evita tudo isso apenas lendo cada pixel. O resultado é um desempenho alto e baixa memória, mas a qualidade fica a desejar.

Se você está lidando apenas com a redução da sua imagem por um pequeno fator, e a filtragem não é um problema, então você não irá encontrar um método tão eficiente de memória como o `inSampleSize`.

**[inScaled, inDensity, inTargetDensity flags](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inScaled)**

Se você precisa para redimensionar uma imagem a uma dimensão que não é atingível com o fator de 2, então você precisará usar os flags do `BitmapOptions`: `inScaled`, `inDensity` e `inTargetDensity`. Quando `inScaled` é setado, o sistema irá buscar o valor de escala adequado para aplicar ao seu bitmap através da divisão dos valores de `inTargetDensity` por `inDensity`.

```
mBitmapOptions.inScaled = true;
mBitmapOptions.inDensity = srcWidth;
mBitmapOptions.inTargetDensity =  dstWidth;

// este método carrega e redimensiona a imagem para a dimensão de 1/inSampleSize
mCurrentBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResources(getResources(), 
      mImageIDs, mBitmapOptions);
```

A utilização deste método irá redimensionar a sua imagem e também aplicar um filtro de redimensionamento. O resultado será aparentemente muito melhor devido à matemática adicional envolvida durante o passo de redimensionamento. Mas preste atenção: **Este passo extra requer um tempo de processamento maior**, e pode rapidamente resolver problemas para grandes imagens, resultando em menores dimensões e alocação extra de memória para o filtro.

Geralmente não é um boa ideia aplicar esta técnica para uma imagem que é significamente maior do que o tamanho desejado, devido ao custo extra de memória do filtro.

### **Combinando Memória e Performance**

No ponto de vista de memória e performance, é possível *combinar* estas opções para obter melhores resultados. (Setando as flags `inSampleSize`, `inScaled`, `inDensity` e `inTargetDensity`).

`inSampleSize` será o primeiro a ser aplicado à imagem, fazendo que esta chegue próxima ao fator de 2 vezes maior do que o tamanho em alvo. Então, `inDensity` & `inTargetDensity` serão usadas para escalar o resultado para as dimensões exatas que você deseja, aplicando um filtro de operação para limpar a imagem.

Combinar estes dois torna a operação muito mais rápida, visto que `inSampleSize` irá reduzir o número de pixels onde o filtro precisará ser aplicado.

```
mBitmapOptions.inScaled = true;
mBitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 4
mBitmapOptions.inDensity = srcWidth;
mBitmapOptions.inTargetDensity =  dstWidth * mBitmapOptions.inSampleSize;

// carrega e redimensiona a imagem para ser da dimensão de 1/inSampleSize
mCurrentBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, mBitmapOptions);
```

Se você precisa encaixar uma imagem em dimensões específicas **e** adicionar bons filtros de imagem, então esta técnica é o melhor caminho para obter o tamanho correto, porém feita de maneira rápida e consumindo pouca memória durante a operação.

### **Obtendo as dimensões de imagem**

Obtendo o tamanho da imagem sem precisar decodificá-la por inteiro.

Para conseguir redimensionar o seu `bitmap`, você precisará saber as dimensões de entrada. Você pode usar a flag `inJustDecodeBounds` para ajudá-lo a pegar as dimensões da imagem, sem necessidade de decodificar os dados.

```
mBitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, mBitmapOptions);
srcWidth = mBitmapOptions.outWidth;
srcHeight = mBitmapOptions.outHeight;

// agora redimensione a imagem para o tamanho que você deseja
```

Você pode usar este flag para decodificar o tamanho primeiramente, e então calcular os valores adequados para a escalar a resolução da sua imagem alvo.

Answer (score -1):

Depois de ter seu bitmap criado, redimensione com o método ***createScaledBitmap()***. Ex:

```
// Cria o objeto
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
// Redimensiona para 60 x 80 px
bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 60, 80, false);
```

Comment: Você leu a pergunta? *O uso de createScaledBitmap pode gerar um monte de erros de falta de memória depois de redimensionar um conjunto de imagens pequenas*.